# Powershell script to run list of sql files

Tags: sql, powershell, cmd

I want to read a file that contains a line separated list of *.sql file names (all located at the same directory) to execute the following:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("_Scripts.txt")
try {
    for(;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        #output
        $out = $line.split(".")[0] + ".txt" ; 

        # -serverinstance  u should change the value of it according to use 
        invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $line -serverinstance "."   | format-table | out-file -filePath $out 
        $line
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

I'm trying to execute this script file by using a batch file containing the command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "_scripts.ps1"
```

but I get the error shown below:

[image]

Can anyone help me fix my ps1 script please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$lines = Get-Content C:\Temp\TEST\_Scripts.txt

ForEach ($line in $lines)
{
    $out = $line.split(".")[0] + ".txt" ;
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $line -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "master" | Format-Table | Out-File -FilePath $out
}
```

Comment: of course you can add the try-catch block and so but basically this works on my machine

Comment: what if I want to exclude database name please ?

Comment: the delete the -Database "master" option in the command above!? Also works without this Parameter

Comment: I have one small issue that the error not write to output file and appear in cmd line

Comment: Maybe you can try the Invoke-Sqlcmd option -OutputSqlErrors.. Have a look a the options in the bottom section of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/cc281720.aspx